# Как применить grid?

Tags: css, css3, sass, less, css-grid

Как применить `grid`, чтобы сделать следующее, чтобы было как на фото?

```css
{
display: grid;
grid: gap;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ Sevastopol' да, спасибо большое!

Comment: Вместо пометки "решено" примите ответ (галочка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.grid__one {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.grid__two {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.grid__one>div,
.grid__two>div {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid__one">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="grid__two">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```